# Making Polygon that covers the Northern hemisphere in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, polygon

In PostGIS, I would expect `ST_Geography` polygons to use a clockwise winding rule, i.e. everything to the right of the edges of the polygon is inside of the polygon.

Therefore, I expected a polygon going over the equator to the west to encompass the entire northern hemisphere, and a polygon going over the equator to the east to encompass the southern hemisphere.

This is not the case, though:

```sql
select st_covers(st_geogfromtext('polygon((0 0, -90 0, -180 0, 90 0, 0 0))'),
       st_geogfromtext('point(0 -5)'))
```

returns `true`, so the polygon going to the west contains a point on the southern hemisphere.

In fact, if I change the direction of the polygon to go to the east, it also contains points on the southern hemisphere, and I can't figure out how to make a polygon that contains points on the northern hemisphere.

So where is my misunderstanding, and how do I create a polygon that contains points on the northern hemisphere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a reference about the winding order and its importance for building a geography object? By a test it does not seem to be so or otherwise one of these polygons would cover almost the whole Earth and have a huge area. In reality both winding orders make the same geography.

```
select st_area(st_geogfromtext('POLYGON (( 20 80, 20 60, 40 60, 20 80 ))'))
"1238730788505.16"

select st_area(st_geogfromtext('POLYGON (( 20 80, 40 60, 20 60, 20 80 ))'))
"1238730788505.16"
```

The documentation https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography says

> **4.2.3.3.** What is the longest arc you can process?
>
> We use great circle arcs as the "interpolation line" between two
>   points. That means any two points are actually joined up two ways,
>   depending on which direction you travel along the great circle. All
>   our code assumes that the points are joined by the *shorter* of the
>   two paths along the great circle. As a consequence, shapes that have
>   arcs of more than 180 degrees will not be correctly modelled.

I feel that a polygon that follows the equator is not well defined because both ways are shorter - or longer. But this is something that I suggest to ask from the PostGIS developers through their mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

I have the impression there is something wrong with the coordinates of your nothern hemisphere polygon. Try with `'polygon((-180 0, -180 90, 180 90, 180 0, -180 0))'` maybe ?

Comment: That doesn't work:

 `select st_covers(st_geogfromtext('polygon((-180 0, -180 90, 180 90, 180 0, -180 0))'), st_geogfromtext('point(0 5)'))` returns `false`

`select st_covers(st_geogfromtext('polygon((-180 0, -180 90, 180 90, 180 0, -180 0))'), st_geogfromtext('point(0 -5)'))` returns `false` as well.

Answer (score 0):

PostGIS has the functions [ST_ForcePolygonCW()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ForcePolygonCW.html) and [ST_ForcePolygonCCW()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ForcePolygonCCW.html), but those are only for geometries, and neither is preferred over the other.

There is no winding rule. The inside of a polygon is the smaller part of the sphere's surface, which is undefined when both parts have the same size. You have to construct the hemisphere from multiple, smaller parts:

```
'MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0, -90 0, -180 0, 0 90, 0 0)), ((0 0, 90 0, 180 0, 0 90, 0 0)))'
```